Best way to consume localstorage in NextJS
I'm trying to make the menu inaccessible if the user doesn't have access.
After the user login, it will return ACL from API and then I store it in locastorage, and from there I only show menus that the user has from locastorage, also show a 404 when user doesn't have access.
The problem is, at first localstorage returns null, but after a second the data is there.
I create an interval to update the data but it seems weird to me (but actually I want to avoid ts error because it says that it has 'any' value).
Is there a better way to consume localstorage for this case?
Thanks in advance
useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      const userInfo: string | null = localStorage.getItem('userInfo');

      if (userInfo) {
        try {
          const userInfoJson: UserInfo = JSON.parse(userInfo);

          if (userInfoJson?.acl) {
            setUserAcl(userInfoJson.acl);
            clearInterval(interval);
          } else if (userInfoJson?.aclCustom) {
            setUserAcl(userInfoJson.aclCustom);
            clearInterval(interval);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.error('Failed to parse userInfo', e);
          setUserAcl([]);
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }
    }, 200);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);


To avoid using intervals listen localstorage with useeffect.


import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [userAcl, setUserAcl] = useState([]);

  const fetchUserInfoFromLocalStorage = () => {
    const userInfo = localStorage.getItem('userInfo');

    if (userInfo) {
      try {
        const userInfoJson = JSON.parse(userInfo);
        if (userInfoJson?.acl) {
          setUserAcl(userInfoJson.acl);
        } else if (userInfoJson?.aclCustom) {
          setUserAcl(userInfoJson.aclCustom);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error('Failed to parse userInfo', e);
        setUserAcl([]);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUserInfoFromLocalStorage();

    const handleStorageChange = (event) => {
      if (event.key === 'userInfo') {
        fetchUserInfoFromLocalStorage();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('storage', handleStorageChange);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('storage', handleStorageChange);
    };
  }, []);

  // Add your logic to render the menu based on userAcl
  // ...

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Your component JSX */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;



